# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: stack

Tags: react-native

I got the following error while running the codes below in React Native.
I tried adding 'const stack' but the error still occurred.
How can I rectify it? Thanks.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: stack

This error is located at:
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name ="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
      </stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Remember that React variable names are case sensitive. Did you mean to have `Stack.Navigator`?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a typo. You have to change <stack.Navigator> to <Stack.Navigator>.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name ="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```